# How could I use Babel standalone to transform an html import to variable?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I would like to use the Babel plugin [babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string) to transform my code in the browser client dynamically. But the babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string is built to run from node with file libraries. But online in the browser I can't use those file libraries.

How could I have Babel Standalone transform this code?

**My Declaration:**

```
import template from './template.html';
```

**Transform To:**

```
var template = '<div>my template<div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to include the plugin code used built in the the babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string transform library.

**Step 1**

Import Babel into the document.

**Step 2**

I then took the code and removed the file libraries and added a string value for the code, html. This code from this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string).

```
 function endsWith(str, search) {
    return str.indexOf(search, str.length - search.length) !== -1;
  }

  // transform `import template from 'file.html';` to a variable `var template = '<div></div>'`;
  function babelPluginImportHtmlToString(o) {
    var t = o.types;
    return {
      visitor: {
        ImportDeclaration: {
          exit: function (path, state) {
            const node = path.node;

            if (endsWith(node.source.value, '.html')) {
              const html = require(node.source.value);

              path.replaceWith(t.variableDeclaration("var", [
                t.variableDeclarator(
                  t.identifier(node.specifiers[0].local.name),
                  t.stringLiteral(html))]));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

**Step 3**

I then registered the function as a Babel plugin. And then called the transform process which uses the plugin.

```
  var plugins = [];
  plugins.push('babelPluginImportHtmlToString');

  babel.registerPlugin('babelPluginImportHtmlToString', babelPluginImportHtmlToString);

  // TODO I'm not showing the babel import statement, include a reference to babel...
  var code = babel.transform(code, {
    filename: filename,
    plugins: plugins,
    presets: presets
  }).code;
```

**Example**

I added support for it in the Sencha Fiddle here. Check out the example here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30vv. If you inspect the devtools, it's going to be in require.js.